# ufw blocking certain traffic on web server that ought to be allowed

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-16.04, ufw

In an Ubuntu 16.04 machine hosting an internet-facing web application, my `/var/log/syslog` is being flooded by messages of the sort:

```
Jan  9 17:41:50 ip-172-31-11-100 kernel: [483324.699896] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens5 OUT= MAC=0a:16:21:97:4e:74:0a:af:bd:31:30:da:08:00 SRC=88.201.58.59 DST=172.31.11.100 LEN=52 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x20 TTL=40 ID=63099 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=6450 DPT=443 WINDOW=343 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0

Jan  9 17:41:50 ip-172-31-11-100 kernel: [483324.719775] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens5 OUT= MAC=0a:16:21:97:4e:74:0a:af:bd:31:30:da:08:00 SRC=88.201.58.59 DST=172.31.11.100 LEN=569 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x20 TTL=40 ID=63098 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=6450 DPT=443 WINDOW=343 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0

Jan  9 17:43:13 ip-172-31-11-100 kernel: [483408.133979] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens5 OUT= MAC=0a:16:21:97:4e:74:0a:af:bd:31:30:da:08:00 SRC=103.255.6.65 DST=172.31.11.100 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=38 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3277 DPT=443 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

It seems user traffic is being blocked from accessing `443` for ttls of up to `40` seconds. I am unable to decipher this issue. Can an expert point out what is going on, and how I can reverse this situation?

Do note that myself and numerous users are able to access this web applcation - i.e. the blocking is not universal. But there are legitimate users complaining about it. Maybe it is a rate-limit issue of some sort?

---

`sudo ufw status verbose` yields:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

`sudo iptables -S | grep ACCEPT` yields:

```
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
```

`sudo iptables -S | grep ufw-user-limit` yields the following (in case **rate-limits** are in play):

```
-N ufw-user-limit
-N ufw-user-limit-accept
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
```

Lastly, `sudo iptables -S | grep "UFW BLOCK"` yields:

```
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
```

Comment: Do you have more log entries? The three shown above look like an attack, not legitimate traffic.

Comment: Might need more than just rules filtered by `grep ACCEPT`.  I'd try `grep "UFW BLOCK"` and work backwards from there.

Comment: @tater - added that output at the end of the question. Is that what you wanted

Comment: @MichaelHampton Can you explain how they are attacks? Yes there are tons more log entries. Unfortunately, I do not understand these log entries, and they are thinly documented online. I have talked to at least one user who is beset by this issue - and they are not an attacker. Their ip does show up in the logs. My guess right now is they are being rate-limited.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before and read a few topics around this on line.

UFW is blocking the RST packets.

https://frankfu.click/linux/basic/ufw-blocking-fin-rst-and-ack-packets-when-rules-should-allow-it/

Answer (score 1):

Very likely these are BLOCKs for invalid packets. Do a tcpdump to capture the packets with something like this and watch for the blocks to happen e.g.:

```
sudo tcpdump port 443 -w /tmp/ufw.log -i eno1 -G 200
```

Break that to stop writing to the output file. Next look at the source port on one of the BLOCKS (SPT=6450 for example) and do a filter to get just the packets for that session into another file:

```
tcpdump -r /tmp/ufw.log -w /tmp/ufw.port6450 port 6450
```

Then look at that output file with wireshark. Very likely those ACK packets will show up in red as spurious retransmissions, and those RST packets are sent after the FIN-ACKs, which make them invalid.